# How to get a proper css code for a gradient?

Tags: css, gradient, photoshop

Usually, when a develop a website from a photoshop .psd file I face hard gradient navigation menus. What is my method? I cut  a small piece of the menu 
and then aplly

```
background-repeat: repeat-x
```

This works just fine. However, I believe it is not the best solution. Is there a correct way or technique to get the proper css code for any gradient?

Comment: Have you tried [online gradient css generator(s)](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)?

Comment: Have you tried **.less**?

Comment: @skobaljic Yes, but I'm interested in other ways. How the rest of FE developers deal with it? Is there an easy way besides online gradient generators?

Comment: @jonamreddy I use Sass.

Comment: I also use SASS. If you want to go to the source then i would suggest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: Or try here: http://www.sitepoint.com/building-linear-gradient-mixin-sass/

Comment: SASS/LESS or if you don't like using these then as @skobaljic says use a generator.

Comment: Really, adding a preprocessor just for the purpose of creating a gradient? I'd recommend learning the CSS markup, it may look overwhelming but is not really that complicated.

Comment: OP stated he is already using SASS.

Answer (score 1):

I use color-picker (adobe photoshop) to get the extreme colors at the menu tab (anchor or li) and then apply simple CSS gradient of CSS3 to get the background color using those 2 extremes (if required you may color-pick intermediate colors). Code goes:

```
nav li{
 /* Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
 background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(top, #c19fd3 , #c39ff3);
/* Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(top, #c19fd3 , #c39ff3);
/* Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(top, #c19fd3 , #c39ff3);
/* Standard syntax */
background: repeating-linear-gradient(top, #c19fd3 , #c39ff3);
}
```

OR

You might get exact colors of a variation is there using percentages in gradients:

```
background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(top, #c19fd3 10% , #c123f9 30%, #c39ff3);
```

It has worked for me.